# The relationship between $\mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{z}$ and the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix and $\mathbf{z}$ be a $n \times 1$ vector.

I am trying to picture the relationship between $\mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{z}$ and the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$.

Using the spectral theorem, we can diagonalize $\mathbf{A}$ as $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{R}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{R}^T$, where $\mathbf{D}$ is diagonal, and its diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{S}$. So $\mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{z} = \mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{R}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{R}^T \mathbf{z} = \mathbf{y}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{y} = \lambda_1 y_1^2 +...+ \lambda_n y_n^2$.

What does $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{R}^T \mathbf{z}$ mean? Is there a
geometric explanation for it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$y = R^\top z$ is a coordinate transformation. Since $R$ is an orthogonal matrix, it represents a change of basis from the standard basis to the orthonormal basis consisting of the colums of $R^\top$. I am not sure what you mean by the relationship between $z^\top A z$ and the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, but one could say it like this. The fact that $A$ is symmetric is equivalent to it being diagonal in some orthonormal basis. This reflects the fact that the corresponding quadratic form $z^\top A z$ can be written without any cross terms using some orthogonal transformation of the variables. I hope this clearifies something for you.